# Algorithm to find smallest difference in array

Tags: algorithms

We want an algorithm that, given an array of length $n$ of integers, find the minimum difference between two integers in the array.

One such algorithm is to sort the array and check adjacent pairs of numbers. This takes time $O(n\log n)$.

Is there a faster way, e.g., an $O(n)$ algorithm?

Comment: It might be worth asking this on the computer science stackexchange instead.